# How to click a button on pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button on my first page.

```
<button id="btm" onclick="window.open('page.htm', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400')">Button1</button>
```

I have another page.htm with below html

```
<button id="testbtn" onclick="window.open('http://www.ivikashjha.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400')">Button2</button>
```

I want to open the website ivikasjha.com on first button click itself.
Actually I want to access controls of pop up page on main parent page.

Comment: You want them both to open at the same time?

Comment: yes @jsve i want both button click on one itself.

Comment: Have you tried calling `window.open` twice, with one to `page.htm` and one to `ivikashjha.com`? You might find that works but causes most browsers to block at least one of the popups to avoid spam.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zp1ocnt/) shows one implementation of what @redbmk mentions in their comment above, but as they correctly predicted, the second window is blocked. Browsers usually block windows from opening when it is not directly opened by a user action (in this case, the first is opened directly by the user, the second is opened as a **result** of the initial click).

Comment: @TimMcClure, there was a little bug in your fiddle. Calling `trigger()` wouldn't actually do anything on it's own. I changed it to `trigger("click")` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3zp1ocnt/1/), and you'll see in Chrome at least a warning that a popup was blocked.

Comment: @redbmk hmm, I was definitely getting a blocked popup for the ESPN site without that, but yours seems like the better alternative. I can't tell from [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) whether the parameter is actually required or optional.

Comment: You will likely need a setTimeout if you are at all allowed to click the other button. Also please remove the spaces in the parameters. Also no need to use =yes: `'toolbar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400'`

Answer (score 1):

## Same domain

An in-browser test (Firefox 35) seems to indicate that if the opened window is inside the same domain, the page has some access

```
var child = window.open( 'http://example.com' )
child.localStorage.setItem( 'hello', 'there' ) // Sets correctly
child.$( 'body' ).css( 'background', 'blue' ) // Access denied to '$'
```

## Different domains

A test across domains, however, seems to restrict the available interface to `location`, `parent`, `postMessage`, and a couple others

```
var child = window.open( 'http://other-domain.com' )
child.localStorage // cannot access
```

[window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is left available to you. Posting messages back and forth between the two tabs isn't the easiest way to do things, but at least you can tell the popup to click it's own button.

If that fails, there's no restrictions on both pages opening up a shared websocket in the background and communicating that way.

## Takeaway

The easiest way to spread functionality between tabs seems to be message posting:

```
//Parent page
var childUrl = 'http://hello.example.com' )
var child = open( childUrl )
child.postMessage( 'click-button', childUrl )

//Child page
window.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ){
  if( event.data === 'click-button' ){
    $( '#my-button' ).click()
  }
}, false )
```